# Using CR in Visual Studio 2010 Targetting .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am working on VS 2010 for a project, targetting the .net 2.0 version.
I want to use crystal report for reporting and since it does not come with CR, I downloaded it from the official website.

When I add any RPT file to my project, it covnverts in .MHT file and upon searching I came to know that its happening because I am targetting .NET 2.0 instead of .NET 4.0.

Is there any way I can target .NET 2.0 and at the same time use CR ?

CORRECTION: it's MHT

Comment: http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first correct `.MTH` it is `.MHT`. Have you download `SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010`

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded and installed CRforVS_13_0.

Comment: you are using it in `WebApplication` or `Windows Application`?

Comment: It's WIndows Application. I am not using .net 4.0 because of it's large size redistribution package and my needs are satisfied by .net 2.0.

Comment: Is that diff. from CRforVS_13_0 ?

Comment: I tried downloading the first one(installation for VS 2010) and the file name is  CRforVS_13_1. I already downloaded  CRforVS_13_0. looking at the file name I guess it's the same thing but diff. version. It shows well in VS but after adding the rpt file, i see MHT file. Weird !

Comment: @Akshay: Have you downloadedt and installed ` SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4`?